# Same query runs usually in seconds but then sometimes does not complete after running for hours

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-sql-database

Appreciate this question title is a bit vague for SO. Apologies for that but I'm at a complete loss about what to do.

I created my first postgres database about a month ago. It's on Azure and has 100GB of storage of which ~40% is currently used.

I have a query that I run via a cron job each morning. Yesterday morning the query ran in under a minute. This morning however it just seemed to time out. There's no significant difference in data volume between yesterday and today.

Resource utilization from the past 7 days:
[image]

Someone suggested it might be the vacuum which I had never heard of before. From a SO post I found on seeing vacuum stats I ran:

```
select
  schemaname, relname,
  last_vacuum, last_autovacuum,
  vacuum_count, autovacuum_count
from pg_stat_user_tables;
```

The vacuum has not run  since February 2nd.

I have access to Azure server over view dashboard but I'm not sure what to look for e.g. DBforPostgreSQL/servers/ourcompany-data/overview

There's activity log, settings and usage alerts but I don't know where I should search for the culprit.

I also looked at active queries to see if there were any still running that I thought were cancelled:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where state = 'active';
```

There are no other running queries.

I have not shared my query here. That's because I don't want to divert any feedback offering optimization tips. I'm aware that I could optimize it by e.g. replacing CTE's with temp tables but I really want to understand the variance in query completion time for the same query. Right now it feels like it's random.

The database is not shared and no other processes or users are on it.

I tried running the query on yesterday's data too, same thing, the query simply does not complete.

Is there any prescribed list of things to check here? Why might a select query that typically completes in a few seconds stop completing seemingly out of the blue?

Comment: There are many good reasons why that can happen: bad statistics, most common values,... You have to capture the execution plan of a slow run. If the query ever finishes, you can use `auto_explain`.